# How to create a maven profile from custom maven mojo

Tags: java, automated-tests, maven-plugin, mojo, maven-profiles

I'm creating my own custom maven mojo to manage custom profiles, I'm using `project.setActiveProfiles(profiles);` to create profiles but I think this method only to activate profiles not create them.

How I can create a new profile from custom maven mojo?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @SilviuBurcea I want to create profiles from maven plugin so I can use it in all projects in my company instead of adding all profiles in all pom.xml files in all projects in my company

Comment: then what J Fabian applies to you, put your profiles in a company wide pom.xml :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create profiles during the build.

If some profiles are needed by several people, put them into the company parent POM.